# Connect my hosted application through nginx in my local machine

Tags: javascript, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have connected hosted web application in local machine through nginx. Application is running on **localhost:447/xyz** . I have edited some file in view(html page) but its not reflected on the browser.
I have checked the root which I mained on the nginx conf file and clear the browser and also checked in incognitomode.

But the changes are not reflecting on the browser.

Below are the details of nginx.conf file and let me know if I did any mistake:-

Thank you

```
server {
    listen       447;
    server_name  localhost;

   

    location / {
        root   D:\projects\\test\test1\src\abc-web\src\main\webapp;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    
    location /mbis/ {
        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:8080/abc/;  
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
    }

    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

}

Folder structure :-

[image]

Comment: I have removed the commented line nginxconfig file and saveit.
I have edited some line of code in html file and saved.  The changes which I have done in html are not reflected in the browser. I removed all commented line from nginxconfig file

Comment: yes Its always showing the orignal file. I am changing the file which is present in the webapp folder

Comment: Yes I have tried in Incogonito window and also edge browser. I have attched image of my folder structure

Comment: `index.jsp` ... so you have java running somehow?

Comment: actually, what does this question have to do with javascript?

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda, It got fixed by using differnet port number.

Comment: nothing to do with me :p